# How to get HTML source of any website with PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, curl, web

I'm trying to get the HTML source from a website using PHP, I've tried the following code and it works correctly for `google.com` and other websites, but it does not work for `facebook.com`

What am I missing?

```
<?php
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'www.facebook.com');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
    $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    $query =  htmlentities($query);
    echo $query;
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could retrieve and look at the headers of your request. There might be something useful in there.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind avoiding "gonna" and "plz" in questions, that is generally appreciated here. This isn't a chat room `:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because facebook runs on **`HTTPS` (SSL Protocol)** . Add this to your existing **`cURL`** parameters

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```